Как в запросе SQL отобразить вместо id значение, соответствующее этим цифрам?
Вот моя БД:

Пишу запрос:
SELECT mydb.teachers.id_department
FROM mydb.teachers
join mydb.department on
teachers.id_department = department.idDepartment
group by id_department

Соответственно, вывод такой:

Но мне нужно, чтобы вместо номеров id были названия кафедр (Department)

Фигня схема. Что мешает одному teacher быть привязанным к двум разным faculty - к одному непосредственно, а к другому через department? А ничто...

@Akina я знаю это. Помогите, пожалуйста, с вопросом.

Вы ж просите вернуть что? id_department Ну его и получаете. Надо название? ну так указывайте правильно поле, в котором это название лежит-хранится. И неясно, зачем потребовалась группировка.

CREATE TABLE teachers (
  idTeachers int,
  FIO varchar(45),
  Post varchar(45),
  id_department INT,
  Gender varchar(45),
  Experience varchar(45)
);

CREATE TABLE department (
  idDepartment int,
  Department varchar(45),
  idFacultu int
);

INSERT INTO teachers (id_department) VALUES (1),(2),(3);

INSERT INTO department VALUES (1, 'Accounting', 1),
(2, 'Information_technologies', 2),
(3, 'Management', 3);

SELECT department.Department 
FROM teachers JOIN department ON teachers.id_department = department.idDepartment;

